# How I can bypass "angular-in-memory-web-api" for a specific url

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api2

I was using "angular-in-memory-web-api" to mock my REST web api, however now I am have started writing the actual web api and I want to replace the "angular-in-memory-web-api" step by step.

Example:
   I have written following asp.net web api 
     /api/values
   however when I  issue http.get() request using above api url angular tries to serve it using "angular-in-memory-web-api", however in this case I want to bypass "angular-in-memory-web-api" so that request is entertained by my actual web api controller.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can set `passThruUnknownUrl` to forward to real backend for un-matching endpoints

e.g.,

```
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {
  passThruUnknownUrl: true
}),
```

Comment: very important to know!

Answer (score 1):

You can try by removing `InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)` from your app.module. If you have done so already, showing some code would be helpful.

Also, consider using Postman to verify your new service

Comment: removing InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService) from app module bypass the in-memory web api in whole, however as mentioned in my question I want to enable disable angular in-memory web api for selective services. Is it possible?

Comment: I see your point now, sorry I didn't get it at first. That's an interesting question. I tried something similar a few days ago unsuccessfully. As stated in the docs: "It intercepts Angular Http requests that would otherwise go to the remote server...". So I think you can't, but you can always create an issue referencing this question, maybe they can help you out

Answer (score 0):

in app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './my-module/services/in-memory-data.service';
```

in app.module.ts imports array

```
HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false, passThruUnknownUrl: true })
```

passThruUnknownUrl [related doc](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api#pass-thru-to-a-live-server)