# How to use angular-in-memory-web-api only for some APIs?

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

I use [`in-memory-web-api`](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) like this:

```js
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    environment.production ?
      [] : HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { delay: 100, passThruUnknownUrl: true }),
    // ...
  ],
```

However, now, I want to use `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule` in dev modde only for some APIs, because only some APIs need to be mocked and not yet have a "real" API to use.

I saw [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076251/how-i-can-bypass-angular-in-memory-web-api-for-a-specific-url), but `passThruUnknownUrl` does it did not work and I want to explicitly define, which URLs to fake and not to fake.

Also `passThruUnknownUrl` does not help, if you just want to use your server API and ignore one locally mocked API for a test, e.g.